# Eshell for RTL File Names

Tags: emacs, eshell

By default, Emacs 24 can handle Arabic, Hebrew, and other right-to-left (RTL) languages.  I have multilingual term emulators that handle this in X, but I would like to use eshell inside emacs to see the non-English character filenames (and boy do I have many).  When I use eshell, the characters are not in the correct order and it spells out gibberish.  `(setq-default bidi-display-reordering t)` (which is default) makes no difference obviously.

Is this possible?

Comment: `eshell` on my setup works with Arabic out of the box.  Do you have the same problem when you use, eg, `shell` instead?  (Curiously, the bidi in `shell` is *almost* but not quite correct in the file listings.)

Comment: One other thing: which font are you using, and does it support the character set you need?

Comment: I use eshell in side of mlterm and running a tmux instance.  The font and mlterm properly render the order in other applications, but not Arabic.  I have wondered maybe

Comment: Your comment got cut off.  Can you get Arabic (or Hebrew) to work at the command line (ie, not running emacs)?  If no, then it's an mlterm problem.  Unicode rxvt for the terminal has worked for me alongside DejaVu Sans Mono for the font to get Arabic to render correctly.  I would imagine the same would work for Hebrew.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  It appears this problem is larger in scale than I thought.  Bidi seems to work in mlterm, mlterm+tmux, but I get problems with a blank `init.el` file even.  [Here is what I am talking about](https://i.imgur.com/M7cLe9Q.png): the characters on right-aligned, but ironically in the wrong order in emacs (this is a test (mlterm) -> tset si a siht (emacs in mlterm)).

Comment: I see what you mean.  Last thing I can think to check: do you get the correct bidi display using the GUI version?  (ie, can you isolate the problem just to emacs in terminal?)

Comment: I stopped using the GUI version a while ago.  I am on Arch, and moved to [emacs-nox package](http://archlinux.org/packages/emacs-nox), removing the X dependencies because I use it in a shell and it always dumps warnings about GTK dependencies when run in daemon-mode.  I tried to find documentation on compile options from Arch maintainers, but it is looking like I should ask elsewhere anyway.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're getting double reordering by emacs + mlterm, and need to disable one.

[Your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPGMZ.png) shows in upper half mlterm successfully detects line-by-line base direction and reorders characters.
And Emacs 24 by default reorders bidi in the terminal, *assuming a non-bidi LTR termianl*.
Combining both results in double reordering ABC -> CBA -> ABC.

You have 2 options:

1. Disable bidi in mlterm (at least while running emacs, not sure how to automate that).
2. Disable bidi in emacs (at least when running under mlterm).
   I.e. set bidi-display-reordering to *nil*, not *t*.

I expect the first will work better. mlterm can only give you a dumb "bidi display" layer, which may be confusing on top of an editor; emacs gives you "bidi editing" where someone thought of how the whole interaction should work.

- Specifically, side-by-side "windows" within emacs should work well when emacs is doing the bidi and break horribly when mlterm is.
- OTOH, mouse copy-paste probably works better when mlterm is doing the bidi.
  If emacs sends reordered chars, that's what mlterm mouse selection will copy.
  Emacs *can* mostly take over mouse with `xterm-mouse-mode` but (untested speculation) it works on terminal coordinates and would need extra work to match them to logical-order text.

P.S. I'm not sure why the end result is right-aligned, as it seems there is a blank line before so Emacs should consider it a new paragraph, decide it's RTL and send right-aligned text to mlterm, and I'd expect mlterm to then reverse the line resulting in it left-aligned.  I'm probably missing something.

Comment: It has been a long time and I subsequently moved to prelude and less manual setup. I forget the elisp but you hit the nail on the head, I eventually toggled the relevant settings.